# Firefox redirect to wrong site based on history

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

So i visited test.mywebsite.com and now when i type mywebsite.com or www.mywebsite.com or even http://www.mywebsite.com it always redirects to test.mywebsite.com

if i use firefox > New Private Windows then i don't have this issue

So it seems if i clear the history it would fix the issue, But i don't want to do that?

Is there any way to disable redirection based on the history or something else is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't clear all the history.

Open history log, search "test.mywebsite.com" and delete those visits.